# Working with positions

Tags: html

I'm currently playing around with HTML and using position to align my div content.

At the moment, I have 3 divs. 2 divs using position:fixed and the other using position:relative.

My two fixed divs span the width of the page at 100% and are aligned at the top of the webpage. Like a top bar.

My third div is placed underneath the top bar with position:relative. The problem i'm having is that the third div is not being positioned underneath the two fixed divs (see picture)

Here is my code:

```
.topbar-container { 
position:fixed; 
width:100%; 
height:72px; 
background-color:#ffffff; 
border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
z-index:2; 
top:0; 
}

.topbar { 
position:fixed;
width:1200px; 
height:72px; 
left:50%; 
margin-left:-600px; 
top:0;
}

.body-container { 
position:relative; 
width:80%; 
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
left:50%; 
margin-left:-600px;  
max-width:1200px; 
border:1px solid red;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="topbar-container"> 
        <div class="topbar"> 

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body-container"> 
    </div>
```

As you can tell by the picture, the div with the red border is being pushed up to the top of the page, where i thought by using position:relative would have fixed the problem.

Could someone please take a look for me?

Thanks in advance

> http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=d96p2ywgzqs5bmnkac7q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` will remove the element from the page flow. You now need to explicitly set the `top` property for `.body-container` to make it appear under the `.topbar-container`:

```
.body-container { 
position:relative; 
width:80%; 
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
left:50%; 
margin-left:-600px;  
max-width:1200px; 
border:1px solid red;
top: 72px; /* must be >= the height of .topbar-container */
}
```

Comment: Ah right, thanks worked great! I can only accept your answer in 6 minutes but will be sure to do so. 

Thanks!!